# Background property of UIButton

Tags: uibutton

I can see that there is a Background property in the Attributes Inspector of UIButton but how do I set it programmatically?

It is not background color or background image because I have tried setting these in code but it doesn't have the desired effect.

Comment: In the attribute inspector of the Interface Builder, the background attribute has as default „Default Background Image“. If you select from the drop down menu an existing image, it is shown as background of the button, at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used setBackgroundImage of UIButton

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure to have a referencing outlet for your button then,

try, `button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black` of course the 'button' name may be diffrent for you and the color of choice may also be.

If this doesn't work for you for some reason this video may be of help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Vq_xckdJkQ